# Find files with lines containing more than one instance of a given character

Tags: terminal

I'm working with a dataset that is split up into multiple files in a directory. The data should be delimited by a given character (in this case semicolon) once per line, however in some places the files have the delimiter more than once per-line, which is causing issues with analysis.

It's not feasable to search for these manually, so what terminal command would I be able to use to identify these offending files?

EDIT: On request, some examples:

The following file would not be reported, as it contains at most one semicolon per line:

```
100238500378 : 1001, 0417, 8432-09
500145287532 : 5a43, 4371097, 9588
255908245-03 : 3570-3, 1507
```

While the following file *would* be reported, as it contains more than one in one of its lines:

```
100238500378 : 1001, 0417, 8432-09
500145287532 : 5a43, 4371097, 9588
23054589808  : 5430958, 234:44, 0476509
255908245-03 : 3570-3, 1507
```

Comment: please give some example lines that should be matched, and line that should not be matched

Comment: @SharuzzamanAhmatRaslan Added.

Comment: There is no one "terminal."  What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Linux, Unix, MacOS or Cygwin on Windows:

```
$ cat test.txt
100238500378 : 1001, 0417, 8432-09
500145287532 : 5a43, 4371097, 9588
23054589808  : 5430958, 234:44, 0476509
255908245-03 : 3570-3, 1507

$ cat test2.txt
100238500378 : 1001, 0417, 8432-09
500145287532 : 5a43, 4371097, 9588
255908245-03 : 3570-3, 1507

$ cat test3.txt
1 : 2, 3, 4
2 : 3:4, 5, 6
3 : 4:5, 6:7, 8
```

If you use ":" as column separator, you would like to have at most 2 column, not more.

With that information, you can use awk to count how many column per line, and only select files that have more than 2 column, and check the content.

Example:

```
$ awk -F":" '{print NF" "FILENAME}' test*.txt
2 test.txt
2 test.txt
3 test.txt
2 test.txt
2 test2.txt
2 test2.txt
2 test2.txt
2 test3.txt
3 test3.txt
4 test3.txt
```

2 column is good, more than 2 is bad. Only select lines that not start with 2, and you will get file that is bad and need fixing

```
$ awk -F":" '{print NF" "FILENAME}' test*.txt |grep -Ev "^2"
3 test.txt
3 test3.txt
4 test3.txt
```